# How to find roles of a user in cloudboost

Tags: cloudboost

I am trying to get all the roles assigned to user when user logs in, using the code below.

```
public class roles extends AsyncTask <String,Void,Void>{

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

           final CloudUser user = new CloudUser();
           final CloudRole role = new CloudRole("MCA");

           user.setUserName(params[0]);
           user.setPassword(params[1]);


               try {
                   user.logIn(new CloudUserCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void done(CloudUser cloudUser, CloudException e) throws CloudException {
                           if (cloudUser != null) {
                               System.out.println("login Successful");
                               System.out.println(cloudUser.getUserName());
                               cloudUser.isInRole(role);
                           }
                           if (e != null) {
                               System.out.println("In logn exception");
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }


                       }
                   });
               } catch (CloudException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }


               return null;
       }
    }
```

**I am getting the following error:**

FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                    Process: com.rakesh_kr.image, PID: 31256
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.cloudboost.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                                                        at io.cloudboost.CloudUser.isInRole(CloudUser.java:335)
                                                                        at com.rakesh_kr.image.MainActivity$roles$1.done(MainActivity.java:174)
                                                                        at io.cloudboost.CloudUser.logIn(CloudUser.java:219)
                                                                        at com.rakesh_kr.image.MainActivity$roles.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:168)
                                                                        at com.rakesh_kr.image.MainActivity$roles.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:155)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that occured in versions of CloudBoost `JavaSDK` prior to `v1.0.7`, this has been fixed, please clone the latest sources from [github](https://github.com/CloudBoost/JavaSDK) or get the latest `jar(1.0.7)` which should be available on [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cloudboost/JavaSDK) in a few hours from now.